# Entity framework example with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

I recently start to learn Entity framework.
I want to use entity framework with asp.net and I try to find EF example with asp.net but there are only example for windows apps.
So, I want simple insert,update,delete sources/examples of LINQ to EF with ASP.net

Answer (score 4):

Just go to this link.

http://www.asp.net/mvc

[Getting Started (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[An Introduction to Entity Framework for Absolute Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B)

[Entity Framework Tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/)

[Getting Started with Entity Framework 5](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/entity-framework5-getting-started)